# Clickhouse Error: DatabaseException: Orig exception: Code: 43

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, clickhouse

I am sending query to clickhouse using sqlalchemy, the query looks like this:

````
def get_active_contract(session: DBSession, **kwargs):
    date = kwargs['date'] if '_date' in kwargs else datetime.today()
    subquery = session.query(
        Contract_State_History.id.label("id"), Contract_State_History.date.label("date"), Contract_State_History.state.label("state"),
        func.rank().over(
            order_by=Contract_State_History.date.desc(),
            partition_by=Contract_State_History.id
        ).label("rnk")
    ).filter(Contract_State_History.date<=date).subquery()
    query = session.query(subquery.c.id.label("contract_id"), 
                        Contract.code.label("contract_code"), 
                        Contract.name.label("contract_name"), 
                        subquery.c.state.label("contract_state"),
                        Contract.number.label("contract_number"))\
        .join(Contract, and_(Contract.id == subquery.c.id, subquery.c.state.in_(['Active','Process','Final','Retry'])))\
        .filter(subquery.c.rnk==1)
    return query
```

This is how Contract_State_History looks from the query above:

`class Contract_State_History(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = '..'

    id = Column("contract_id", String, primary_key=True)
    _date = Column("period", DateTime, primary_key=True)
    state = Column("state_", String)

    @hybrid_property
    def date(self):
        return func.dateadd(text("month"), func.date_diff(text("month, 0"), self._date), 0)`
```

and this is how I was sending the query: 

```
conn_str = 'clickhouse:...'
engine = create_engine(conn_str) 
conn = engine.connect()
session = Session(bind=engine)
df = get_active_contract(session).all()
pd.DataFrame(df)
```
usually I would recieve the result of query and put it in DataFrame, but instead I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DatabaseException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df = get_active_contract(session).all()
      2 pd.DataFrame(df)

File /db/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:2768, in Query.all(self)
   2752 def all(self):
   2753     """Return the results represented by this :class:`_query.Query`
   2754     as a list.
   2755 
   (...)
   2766             :ref:`faq_query_deduplicating`
   2767     """
-> 2768     return self._iter().all()

File /db/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:2903, in Query._iter(self)
   2900 params = self._params
   2902 statement = self._statement_20()
-> 2903 result = self.session.execute(
   2904     statement,
   2905     params,
   2906     execution_options={"_sa_orm_load_options": self.load_options},
   2907 )
   2909 # legacy: automatically set scalars, unique
   2910 if result._attributes.get("is_single_entity", False):

File /db/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py:1696, in Session.execute(self, statement, params, execution_options, bind_arguments, _parent_execute_state, _add_event, **kw)
   1694 else:
   1695     conn = self._connection_for_bind(bind)
-> 1696 result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
   1698 if compile_state_cls:
   1699     result = compile_state_cls.orm_setup_cursor_result(
   1700         self,
   1701         statement,
   (...)
   1705         result,
   1706     )

File /db/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1631, in Connection._execute_20(self, statement, parameters, execution_options)
   1627     util.raise_(
   1628         exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(statement), replace_context=err
   1629     )
   1630 else:
-> 1631     return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)

File /db/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:325, in ClauseElement._execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params, execution_options, _force)
    321 def _execute_on_connection(
    322     self, connection, multiparams, params, execution_options, _force=False
    323 ):
    324     if _force or self.supports_execution:
--> 325         return connection._execute_clauseelement(
    326             self, multiparams, params, execution_options
    327         )
    328     else:
    329         raise exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(self)

File /db/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1498, in Connection._execute_clauseelement(self, elem, multiparams, params, execution_options)
   1486 compiled_cache = execution_options.get(
   1487     "compiled_cache", self.engine._compiled_cache
   1488 )
   1490 compiled_sql, extracted_params, cache_hit = elem._compile_w_cache(
   1491     dialect=dialect,
   1492     compiled_cache=compiled_cache,
   (...)
   1496     linting=self.dialect.compiler_linting | compiler.WARN_LINTING,
   1497 )
-> 1498 ret = self._execute_context(
   1499     dialect,
   1500     dialect.execution_ctx_cls._init_compiled,
   1501     compiled_sql,
   1502     distilled_params,
   1503     execution_options,
   1504     compiled_sql,
   1505     distilled_params,
   1506     elem,
   1507     extracted_params,
   1508     cache_hit=cache_hit,
   1509 )
   1510 if has_events:
   1511     self.dispatch.after_execute(
   1512         self,
   1513         elem,
   (...)
   1517         ret,
   1518     )

File /db/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1862, in Connection._execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, execution_options, *args, **kw)
   1859             branched.close()
   1861 except BaseException as e:
-> 1862     self._handle_dbapi_exception(
   1863         e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
   1864     )
   1866 return result

File /db/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:2047, in Connection._handle_dbapi_exception(self, e, statement, parameters, cursor, context)
   2043         util.raise_(
   2044             sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
   2045         )
   2046     else:
-> 2047         util.raise_(exc_info[1], with_traceback=exc_info[2])
   2049 finally:
   2050     del self._reentrant_error

File /db/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py:207, in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    204     exception.__cause__ = replace_context
    206 try:
--> 207     raise exception
    208 finally:
    209     # credit to
    210     # https://cosmicpercolator.com/2016/01/13/exception-leaks-in-python-2-and-3/
    211     # as the __traceback__ object creates a cycle
    212     del exception, replace_context, from_, with_traceback

File /db/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1819, in Connection._execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, execution_options, *args, **kw)
   1817                 break
   1818     if not evt_handled:
-> 1819         self.dialect.do_execute(
   1820             cursor, statement, parameters, context
   1821         )
   1823 if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:
   1824     self.dispatch.after_cursor_execute(
   1825         self,
   1826         cursor,
   (...)
   1830         context.executemany,
   1831     )

File /db/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/clickhouse_sqlalchemy/drivers/base.py:390, in ClickHouseDialect.do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    389 def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 390     cursor.execute(statement, parameters, context=context)

File /db/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/clickhouse_sqlalchemy/drivers/http/connector.py:122, in Cursor.execute(self, operation, parameters, context)
    119 params = {'query_id': self._query_id}
    120 response_gen = transport.execute(raw_sql, params=params)
--> 122 self._process_response(response_gen)
    123 self._end_query()

File /db/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/clickhouse_sqlalchemy/drivers/http/connector.py:221, in Cursor._process_response(self, response)
    218 def _process_response(self, response):
    219     response = iter(response)
--> 221     self._columns = next(response, None)
    222     self._types = next(response, None)
    223     self._response = response

File /db/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/clickhouse_sqlalchemy/drivers/http/transport.py:131, in RequestsTransport.execute(self, query, params)
    126 def execute(self, query, params=None):
    127     """
    128     Query is returning rows and these rows should be parsed or
    129     there is nothing to return.
    130     """
--> 131     r = self._send(query, params=params, stream=True)
    132     lines = r.iter_lines()
    133     try:

File /db/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/clickhouse_sqlalchemy/drivers/http/transport.py:177, in RequestsTransport._send(self, data, params, stream)
    175     orig = HTTPException(r.text)
    176     orig.code = r.status_code
--> 177     raise DatabaseException(orig)
    178 return r

DatabaseException: Orig exception: Code: 43. DB::Exception: Second argument for function dateDiff must be Date or DateTime: While processing (0 + toIntervalMonth(dateDiff('month', 0, period))) <= '2022-12-07 16:17:49'. (ILLEGAL_TYPE_OF_ARGUMENT) (version 22.4.2.1 (official build))
```
````

I have tried changing hybrid property from:

```
    @hybrid_property
    def date(self):
        return func.dateadd(text("month"), func.date_diff(text("month, 0"), self._date), 0)`
```

to:

```
    @hybrid_property
    def date(self):
        return func.date_trunc('month', self._date)
```

but this time got different error message:

```
DatabaseException: Orig exception: Code: 53. DB::Exception: Cannot convert string 2022-12-07 16:48:25 to type Date: while executing 'FUNCTION lessOrEquals(date_trunc('month', period) : 3, '2022-12-07 16:48:25' : 2) -> lessOrEquals(date_trunc('month', period), '2022-12-07 16:48:25') Nullable(UInt8) : 4'. (TYPE_MISMATCH) (version 22.4.2.1 (official build))
```

So, here I am seeking for your help :/
Not really sure how to solve it, and getting it to work with data type of "DateTime"
What would you recomend?

Comment: I'm also facing this issue